# continuous function and not differentiable

Tags: calculus, analysis, reference-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Function example? Continuous everywhere, differentiable nowhere](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/31054/function-example-continuous-everywhere-differentiable-nowhere)

Is there any function that continuous in all places and not differentiable in all places?

do you know a good book about this?

Comment: I added the reference-request tag as you ask for a book.

Comment: Nice additional information: A randomly chosen continuous function is nearly "always" not differentiable in all places. For example the continous functions on $\left[0,1\right]$ that are not differentiable in all places are dense in all continous function on $\left[0,1\right]$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a look at the [Weierstrass function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function). There you can also find a list of references. "Counterexamples in analysis" of Gelbaum and Olmstead sounds very promising.